# React-select/async not showing options to filter

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to get some data from mongodb to the select option then i can filter them then select an option but it doesn't display any data from the API

```
 const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
 const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');

  
    const handleUser = value => {
       setSelectedValue(value);
    }
  
    const handleInputChange = value => {
      setValue(value);
    };
const loadOptions = async (inputValue) => {
    return await axios.get('/user/' + inputValue).then(res => res.json());
  };
 <AsyncSelect
       cacheOptions
       defaultOptions
       value={selectedValue}
       loadOptions={loadOptions}
       onInputChange={handleInputChange}
       onChange={handleUser}
  />
```

am i missing something with my code ?

Comment: what is AsyncSelect? what is the import statement for that, can you provide full code for your component with import statement?

Comment: AsyncSelect is a react library that you can use to select a specific value from the database its a select option HTML but with a filter inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Function that returns a promise, which is the set of options to be
> used once the promise resolves.

for async:

```
const getData = async (inputValue) => {
  let res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  return res.data;
};
const getData2 = () => {
  axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((res) => res.data);
};
const loadOptions = (inputValue) => {
  return getData(inputValue).then((res) => {
    return res
      .filter((r) => r.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue))
      .map((t) => ({ value: t.id, label: t.name }));
  });
};

export const RenderSelect = () => {
  return <AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={loadOptions} />;

};
}
```

[image: Edit codesandboxer-example (forked)]

Comment: Thank you so much its working , but i have a question please how can i take the selectedValue and put it inside another axios function to display data from a single row ?

Comment: i solved the issue i made another async function and get selectedValue.label into params then saved it to useState and everything is working now ♥